# Leaflet Easybutton does't show up

Tags: leaflet, easybutton-plugin

[image]I can't figure out why the EasyButton does't work. The following is the result of many modifications but none of them work as expected.

Simple Leaflet Map

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>

<style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

```
<script
    src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
</script>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([52.2858, 5.78682], 14);
    mapLink =
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; ' + mapLink,
            maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);


    var helloPopup = L.popup().setContent('Hello World!');

    L.easyButton('fa-globe', function (btn, map) {
        helloPopup.setLatLng(map.getCenter()).openOn(map);
    }).addTo(map);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you copied the whole of your code, but here are several things that need to be corrected.

Links to `leaflet.css` and `font-awesome.css` are missing:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
```

And what is most importatnt, `leaflet.js` script should be included before `easy-button.js`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added an image of the whole of the  code because the code was not listed completely. And F12 lists:  Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined

Comment: As I wrote in may answer, that's because you are including `easy-button.js` before `leaflet.js` (see second part of my answer). And please never give pictures of your code, always actual code text.